# How can I search an std::map using a key of a different type

Tags: c++, performance, dictionary, stl, comparator

If I have `std::map<X, Blah>`, what is the best way of looking up a matching item in the map using an instance of `Y`?

Assume the information in `Y` is enough to uniquely find an `X`, but for performance reasons I don't want to create an instance of `X` by copying `Y` values.

I realize I can do this by creating a common base class or interface for `X` and `Y` and making that the map key, but is there any other way? e.g. creating some sort of comparator object?

Here is the sample code for clarity:

```
class X
{
public:
    int id;
    int subId;
};

std::map<X, Details> detailsMap;

class Y
{
public:
    int getId();
    int getSubId();
    int someOtherUnrelatedThings1;
    int someOtherUnrelatedThings2;
};
```

Now, if I have an instance of `Y`, in principle I should be able to find matching items in my map, given I can get an `id` and `subId` pair. But can I do it without creating an instance of `X` and copying over the `id` and `subId`?

Comment: Maybe use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)?

Comment: `std::map<X, Details, std::less<>>`

Comment: The map definition shouldn't change right? All it needs to know is that I want want to index by X instances. I simply want to be able to come later and say "please use this Y instance to search, as it has everything you need to match an X"

Comment: Possibly an XY problem? :P Really though, can you add `X& getX()` to `Y`?

Comment: @Dieter Imagine X and Y are part of different projects, owned by different people.

Comment: @Nick, to add an `X& getX() to Y`, I would have to make the implementation Y be able to create an instance of X (which I don't want for performance reasons), or make Y inherit from X, which is awful cause I don't want Y to inherit X fields - see the example.

Comment: Hence, you have to copy

Comment: @nappyfalcon unless you provide a custom comparator (a transparent one as I suggested), you won't be able to get away without an instance of `X` from `Y`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki By custom comparator do you mean as part of the map definition itself? But what if you have many different classes like Y, Z, P, Q all of which can match an X in some logical way?

Comment: @nappyfalcon `std::less<>` is a transparent comparator, it can handle all your cases

Comment: @JoachimPileborg As far as I can see, find_if is for iterating through a list in log(N) time...? It won't do a fast map lookup? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: "but for performance reasons I don't want to create an instance of X by copying Y values" Do you have a profiler run to back up this claim? The reason I'm asking is that in nearly all cases when "performance reasons" are cited as a reason to do or not to do something, it turns out that these "performance reasons" are purely speculative. They exist in programmer's mind alone, and have nothing to do with reality.

Comment: "Imagine X and Y are part of different projects, owned by different people" Which side do you own, the one with `X` or the one with `Y`?

Comment: @nappyfalcon http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8b5ffd24250960a

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With C++14 you can use heterogeneous lookup.

If you'd like to find an element with key that compares *equivalent* to the argument of `std::map::find`, you should provide a Comparator as a third template parameter which should have `Comparator::is_transparent` denoted as a type. It should also contain `bool operator()` comparing your map key with any other type you'd like.

Funny description aside, here's an example:

```
struct X
{
    int id;
    int subid;
};

struct Details {};

struct Comparator
{
    using is_transparent = std::true_type;

    // standard comparison (between two instances of X)
    bool operator()(const X& lhs, const X& rhs) const { return lhs.id < rhs.id; }

    // comparison via id (compares X with integer)
    bool operator()(const X& lhs, int rhs) const { return lhs.id < rhs; }
    bool operator()(int lhs, const X& rhs) const { return lhs < rhs.id; }

    // Same thing with Y
    bool operator()(const X& lhs, const Y& rhs) const { return lhs.id < rhs.getId(); }
    bool operator()(const Y& lhs, const X& rhs) const { return lhs.getId() < rhs.id; }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<X, Details, Comparator> detailsMap = {
        { X{1, 2}, Details{} }, 
        { X{3, 4}, Details{} },
        { X{5, 6}, Details{} }
    };

    // it1 and it2 point to the same element.
    auto it1 = detailsMap.find(X{1, 2});
    auto it2 = detailsMap.find(1);

    std::cout << detailsMap.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (it1 == detailsMap.end()) << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (it1 == it2) << std::endl; // true
}
```

Note however that GCC didin't implement it until revision [219888](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=219888).

Comment: Unfortunately we use C++98, I should have mentioned it. :-( But I've ticked it anyway, as I'll take it from all the answers here that there is no good solution before C++14?

Comment: Instead of defining new class `Comparator`, you can overload `template<>
struct std::less<X>
`

Answer (score 1):

C++14 added `is_transparent` support to `map` orderings.

```
struct compare_helper {
  X const* px = nullptr;
  Y const* py = nullptr;
  compare_helper(compare_helper&&)=default;
  compare_helper(X const& x):px(&x) {}
  compare_helper(Y const& y):py(&y) {}
  explicit operator bool()const{return px&&py;}
  friend bool operator<(compare_helper&& lhs, compare_helper&& rhs) {
    if (!lhs || !rhs) {
      return !rhs < !lhs;
    }
    // TODO: compare lhs and rhs based off px and py
  }
};
struct ordering_helper {
  using is_transparent=std::true_type;
  bool operator()(compare_helper lhs, compare_helper rhs)const{
    return std::move(lhs)<std::move(rhs);
  }
};
```

now redefine your `std::map`:

```
std::map<X, Details, ordering_helper> detailsMap;
```

and you are done.  You can now pass an `Y const&` to `detailsMap.find` or whatever.

Now `// TODO: compare lhs and rhs based off px and py` is a bit annoying.

But it should be writable.

If you need many different classes to be able to compare against `X`, and you either need a large `compare_helper` class with each saved, or you need to type-erase the operation somehow.

Basically, `compare_helper` needs to store a pointer-to-`X`, or a `std::function< int(X const&) >` which tells you if the `X` is less than, equal to, or greater than the other parameter.  (you'll note this fails when comparing a `Y` against a `Y` or a `Z` against a `Y` -- in that case, returning false should be safe, as you'll only ever see one non-`X` in a given map search).

We can decouple this from the definition of `compare_helper` with some ADL:

```
struct compare_helper {
  X const* px = nullptr;
  using f_helper = std::function< int(X const&) >;
  f_helper not_X;
  compare_helper(compare_helper&&)=default;
  compare_helper(X const& x):px(std::addressof(x)) {}
  template<class NotX,
    class=std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<
      decltype(compare_with_X( std::forward<NotX>(notx) ))
      , f_helper
    >{}
  >
  compare_helper( NotX&& notx ):
    not_X( compare_with_X( std::forward<NotX>(notx) ) )
  {}
  explicit operator bool()const{return px&&not_X;}
  friend bool operator<(compare_helper&& lhs, compare_helper&& rhs) {
    if (!lhs || !rhs) {
      return !rhs < !lhs;
    }
    if (lhs.px && rhs.px) { return *lhs.px < *rhs.px; }
    if (lhs.px && rhs.not_X) { return rhs.not_X(*lhs.px) < 0; }
    if (lhs.not_X && rhs.px) { return lhs.not_X(*rhs.px) > 0; }
    else return false;
  }
};
```

now the end-user simply has to override the free function `compare_with_X` in the namespace of the type you want to compare with `X` to return a `std::function<int(X const&)>`, and the above map allows lookup from your non-`X` type.