# Overload std::map with different key type

Tags: c++, stl

So I have the following STL `std::map` container

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
// ...
class Type
{
 std::string key;
 int support;
};
std::map<Type, std::vector<int> > index;
```

I want to overload the map so both if clauses below work:

```
int main()
{
  std::map<Type, std::vector<int> > index;
  Type type1;
  type1.key = "test";
  type1.support = 10;
  index[type1] = std::vector<int>();
  if (index.find(type1) != index.end())
  {
    index[type1].push_back(0);
  }
  // I can not make this work
  if (index.find("test") != index.end())
  {
    index["test"].push_back(0);
  }


  return 0;
}
```

I have tried these overloads:

```
class Type 
{
 public:
  std::string key;
  int support;
  size_t operator()() const
  {
    return std::hash<std::string>{}(name);
  }

  bool operator==(const struct Type& obj) const 
  {
    return (key == obj.key);
  }

  bool operator<(const struct Type& obj) const 
  {
    return key < obj.key;
  }

  bool operator<(const std::string& other_key) const 
  {
    return key < other_key;
  }


  bool operator==(const std::string& other_key) const
  {
    return other_key == key;

  }


};

namespace std
{

  template<>
  struct hash<Type>
  {
    size_t operator()(const Type& obj) const
    {
      return obj();
    }
    // Specialization here does not seem to work
    size_t operator()(const std::string& name) const
    {
      return std::hash<std::string>{}(name);
    }
  };

  template<>
  struct less<Type>
  {

    bool operator() (const std::string& lname, const std::string& rname)
    {
      return lname < rname;
    }
  };
```

Since in my model the `std::string key` field uniquely defines the Type how can I overload the `std::map` container so that can index the items of the container? Am I able to do that in C++?

PS: I know that some code might be redundant in the overloads

Comment: You can do that for `std::map::find()` but you cannot do that for `std::map::operator[]` so you either create temprorary `Type` or only use `find`

Comment: Sounds like you just need to give `Type` constructors that take either type. The challenge then might be to make them properly comparable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that is not necessary for `std::map::find()` since c++14

Comment: @Slava I'm not sure what *"that"* refers to in your comment.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux by "that" I mean that you do not have to create instance of `Type` to pass it to `find`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is called heterogeneous lookup and supported by `std::map` since C++14. For that you can define your own comparator structure and provide type `is_transparent` in it to enable this functionality. Details on how to enable heterogeneous lookup can be found here [How can I search an std::map using a key of a different type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923715/how-can-i-search-an-stdmap-using-a-key-of-a-different-type)

Also note, while `std::map::find()` does support it `std::map::operator[]` does not, so you have to replace your code:

```
if (index.find("test") != index.end())
{
   index["test"].push_back(0);
}
```

to something like:

```
 auto it = index.find("test");
 if( it != index.end()) 
     it->second.push_back(0);
```

and you should do that anyway, as you would do two lookups instead of one otherwise and that is significantly expensive operation on map.

So for your case comparator should be something like:

```
struct CompareType
{
    using is_transparent = std::true_type;

    // standard comparison (between two instances of Type)
    bool operator()(const Type& lhs, const Type& rhs) const { return lhs.key < rhs.key; }
    // comparisons btw Type and std::string
    bool operator()( const Type& lhs, const std::string &rhs) const { return lhs.key < rhs; }
    bool operator()(const std::string &lhs, const Type& rhs) const { return lhs < rhs.key; }
};
```

then you create your map by:

```
std::map<Type, std::vector<int>,CompareType> index;
```

and you do not need comparison methods in `Type` itself anymore

Another way is to submit `std::less<>` as third parameter to `std::map`, but in that case you are missing the comparison operator, that takes `std::string` as left operand and `Type` as right and as that comparison operator cannot be member of `Type` I think it is cleaner to do it through a separate comparator (code there is consistent).

Comment: I had no idea this was possible. I have so much catching up to do since C++11.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems in the code as provided:

1. The Type class doesn't support less-than operation, which is required when used as std::map<> key type.
2. A string (char array constant) is used in two places where Type is expected: argument of `map::find()` and `map::operator[]`. Compiler can't convert from const char* to Type.

First, meet requirement for Type as a key type of std::map<>:

```
// Define comparison/ordering of two Type instances
bool operator<(const Type& a, const Type& b)
{
   return a.key < b.key;
}
```

Second, define how const char* (e.g. "test") may be implicitly converted to Type using single-arg ctor:

```
class Type 
{
public:
   // Implicitly converts const char* value to instance of Type.
   Type(const char* k) : key(k), support(0) {}
   //...
};
```

This doesn't require any newer (C++11 or C++14) language features.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply this:

```
std::map<Type, std::vector<int>, std::less<> > index;
```

This requires C++14.  Note the use of `std::less` with no template argument, which allows searching for "compatible" keys, not only the exact `key_type`.  That's what you need to "unlock" the use of `find()` with your custom comparison functions.

The default third template argument for `std::map` is `std::less<key_type>`, which is more limited.  It remains this way for backward compatibility with pre-C++14 code, but much new code would do well to use `std::less` without template arguments.

Comment: Are you sure? This doesn't compile. Where did you find this?

Comment: You need `std::less<>` actually.

Comment: @n.m. `std::less<void>` seems to enable heterogenous lookup indeed https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void

Comment: @Slava yes the feature is here, just with a bit different syntax.