# Safe way to use string_view as key in unordered map

Tags: c++, c++17

My type Val contains std::string thekey.

```
struct Val
{
std::string thekey;
float somedata;
}
```

I would like put my type in an unordered map, with thekey as key. For memory and conversion avoidance reasons I would like to have std::string_view as key type. Is it possible to have the key created to point to val.thekey, while using unique_ptr ?

```
std::unique_ptr<Val> valptr = ...;
std::unordered_map<std::string_view,std::unique_ptr<Val>> themap;
themap[std::string_view(valptr->thekey)] = std::move(valptr); // is this ok and safe?
```

Comment: This seems like it's unneeded.  If you use an `unordered_set`, you can create your own hasher and comparator that just uses `thekey` and then you save the cost of having a `string_view`.

Comment: `themap[std::string_view(valptr->thekey)] = std::move(valptr);` would not be safe if the key is already in the map (the old std::string_view would remain while the old Val gets destructed), apart from that it should be safe if you're very careful - [see other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51751115/8411406)

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9oG1ozbdc) to thing described by @Turtlefight

Comment: @NathanOliver That would solve the memory part, nice. The second part: I am concerned themap.find(aStringView) would be slow due to the required type conversion of input key. In my case the key I am searching with is string_view.

Comment: It is cumbersome to use and error-prone

Comment: @Johan No conversion is needed.  Since C++14, the hasher and comparator are allowed to be "transparent" and have overloads to treat other types as the same type as the key: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators

Comment: @nathan you sure about the unordered containers?  I thought that was 20 not 14.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Woops.  Yep, that was C++20 for the unordered containers.  I would have though that was added for all of them in C++14, but I guess not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Safe way to use string_view as key in unordered map

*In general* there isn't one, because the storage underlying the view might change at any time, invalidating your map invariants.

Associative containers generally *own* a `const` key precisely to avoid this.

*In your specific case* it makes much more sense to use `std::unordered_set<Val, ValKeyHash, ValKeyEqual>` with suitable hash and equality functors.

---

Edit, these suitable functors are simply

```
struct ValKeyHash {
    std::size_t operator() (Val const &v)
    {
        return std::hash<std::string>{}(v.thekey);
    }
};

struct ValKeyEqual {
    bool operator() (Val const& a, Val const& b)
    {
        return a.thekey == b.thekey;
    }
};
```

Obviously this leaves us with the slightly unhappy requirement of using a temporary `Val{key, dummy_data}` for lookups, at least until we can use the C++20 transparent/projected version in the other answer.

Comment: You should describe the suitable functors

Comment: If this answer would would show suitable functors or point in the right direction for learning about it, then I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), you should do this

```
namespace utils {
  // adl hash function:
  template<class T>
  auto hash( T const& t )
  ->decltype( std::hash<T>{}(t) )
  { return std::hash<T>{}(t); }

  // Projected hasher:
  template<class Proj>
  struct ProjHash {
    template<class T>
    constexpr std::size_t operator()(T const& t)const {
      return hash(Proj{}(t));
    }
    using is_transparent=std::true_type;
  };

  // Projected equality:
  template<class Proj>
  struct ProjEquals {
    template<class T, class U>
    constexpr std::size_t operator()(T const& t, U const& u)const {
      return std::equal_to<>{}( Proj{}(t), Proj{}(u) );
    }
    using is_transparent=std::true_type;
  };
}

// A projection from Val to a string view, or a string view
// to a string view:
struct KeyProj {
  std::string_view operator()(Val const& val) const { return val.thekey; }
  std::string_view operator()(std::string_view sv) const { return sv; }
};

std::unordered_set<Val, ProjHash<KeyProj>, ProjEquals<KeyProj>> theset;
```

now you can

```
theset.find("hello")
```

to find the element of the set whose key is `"hello"`.

---

A map is fundamentally wrong here, because the features that a map has that the above set does not don't do the right things.  Like `mymap["hello"]`, which goes and creates a `Val` if it isn't found; we now have a dangling string view in the container.

An intrusive map in `std` is a set with a projection, not a map with a reference into the value as a key.