# string_view as a key of unordered_map

Tags: c++, string, c++17

When using `std::string_view` as a key in a map, are we responsible for making sure the underlying string/char we used to create the `std::string_view` is still alive. Reason why I ask this, is because I am seeing very strange behaviour with my map. After I emplace my second key, the first key gets overwritten by the second key.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string_view, std::unique_ptr<CustomClass> > m_map;

emplace_in_map(std::string_view str, std::unique_ptr<CustomClass> ccc){
   m_map.emplace(str, std::move(ccc));
}
 wrapper(std::string str) {
     // create ccc
    emplace_in_map(str, ccc);
  }

main(){
     wrapper("test1");
     wrapper("test2"); // after this test1 key get overwritten by test2
     
 }
```

After the second call I have a map with two keys that are both equal to `test2`

Comment: If course yes, you are responsible. **Notes
It is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that std::string_view does not outlive the pointed-to character array**

Comment: Yes, you need to keep the string alive. String literals stay alive during the entire program execution, but `string_view` binds not to a literal but the `string` parameter, which dies shortly.

Comment: Maybe see this: [Safe way to use string_view as key in unordered map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69678864/safe-way-to-use-string-view-as-key-in-unordered-map). It seems a highly similar question.

Comment: Ask yourself - what is the lifetime of `std::string str`?  That function parameter is **every** string you're trying to _view_ later.

Comment: Btw, STL containers aren't great at handling `string_view`. For example, `std::set<std::string>` would not support `find(std::string_view)`. One of the ways around this is using Abseil maps/sets, because they feature [heterogeneous lookup](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/container#heterogeneous-lookup).

Answer (score 2):

If you deal with string literals, this will work

```
template <size_t N>
wrapper(const char (&str)[N]) {
  // create ccc
  emplace_in_map(str, ccc);
}
```

In other cases [Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view#sNotes)

> It is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that `std::string_view` does not outlive the pointed-to character array

Comment: `wrapper(std::string_view str)` would also work.  Assuming all these functions were given return types.

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes, it will work in this tiny example, unless OP attempts using `wrapper` with pointers `const char*` to temp arrays or local arrays `char[N]`.

Comment: `const char*(&str)[N]` is a (reference to) an array of pointers. You can't initialize that array with a string literal. I think you meant `const char (&str)[N]` for a single string literal instead.  Or, you could just use `const char* str` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for finding the typo! I would not like using `const char* str` for avoiding issues while calling `wrapper` with local or temp char arrays.

Comment: I don't like the idea of using an array reference as a heuristic to reject non-static strings. You could create a local array that goes of scope, and you could have a pointer to a static string.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Of course it does not cover such cases, but prevents from at least a couple other "bad" cases. As I know there is no standard or a portable way of detecting string literals.